# Divs for containing image and caption (as image)

Tags: html, css

I have been going nuts trying to figure out why this isn't working.  I have researched it a lot and can't seem to find the right answer:

I am simply trying to make set of DIV items act like a vertically stacked two-cell table where the table displays inline so that it can span across the screen and break like text (for responsive appearance).  The top cell and the bottom cell are fixed sizes and the images within each (one art thumbnail and one handwritten caption) are centered vertically and horizontally within their cells.  Here is my code:

**CSS & HTML**

```css
div.artpluslabel {
 width: 275px;
 height: 375px;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-table;
}

div.artContainer {
 width: 275px;
 height: 325px;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

div.label {
 width: 275px;
 height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="artpluslabel">
    <div class="artContainer">
        <a href = "art.php?id=', $ids[$i], '">
            <img class = "art" src = "img/art/filename.gif">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="label">
        <a href = "art.php">
            <img src = "img/art_labels/filename.png">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyway, ignore the "art" class for the image, as the only thing it does is add a border.

I don't understand why this doesn't appear correctly.  This should be a basic thing.  What happens is the label portion overlaps the art image instead of stacking underneath.

Anybody see the problem?  I've spent quite some time trying to fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: You code doesn't show anything,..perhaps with some real images and text ut might be clearer..or perhaps an image of what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="artpluslabel">
    <div class="artContainer">
        <a href = "art.php?id=', $ids[$i], '">
            <img class = "art" src = "img/art/filename.gif">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="label">
        <a href = "art.php">
            <img src = "img/art_labels/filename.png">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.artpluslabel {
    display: flex;
    justiy-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 550px;
}

.artContainer, .label {
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

I am not sure about this. I used flexbox all the time because it works well for me. Try this.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't have the inline effect of wrapping across the screen.  Do you have any suggestions for that?  Do I have to use another div container?

Comment: Show me an image. So I can help you.

Comment: I want it to display left-to-right and break across the div, not top-to-bottom

Comment: I ended up using a mixture of table styles and your code, so it worked!